# Slick Slider slidesToScroll modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick-2.0, slick.js

I use the slick slider on my site. And no matter how much I was pulling the slider to the left or to the right, it just runs only on the number of slides that is specified in the property slidesToScroll. Is it possible to do something with slick slider that it worked like this slider http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/mousewheel.html. How much do you pulling - it scroll the same distance. Sorry for my english. Thanks you.

There is my code for init slick slide:

```
 $('.slider-wrapper-2').slick({
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 4,
        rows: 1
    });
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackExchange. Please edit your question and update with your own code, so someone can tell you how to fix it. We can't do anything for you if we don't know the code you wrote.

Comment: I use Slick @Денис Яломист and I must admit that I've never come across this option. The touch panning is a 'swipe', specifically - rather than a proper pan. Have you gone over the docs to make sure there isn't an option for what you need?

Comment: I didnt find that option in slick slider docs. So i asked here about this option, maybe somebody faced with this problem. Maybe something can be corrected in slick.js file. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just add the `swipeToSlide` setting, which enables swiping to any slide irrespectively to `slidesToScroll`

Your initializing script should look like this:

```
$('.slider-wrapper-2').slick({
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 4,
    rows: 1,
    swipeToSlide: true
});
```

In case it doesn't work, remove the `slidesToScroll` option. Please comment how it worked so I can edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

swipeToSlide: true

Adding swipeToSlide option does the job, even with slidesToScroll enabled. No need to disable slidesToScroll.